# How to enable https for Keycloak in a Jhipster generated project?

Tags: jboss, jhipster, keycloak

I am trying to enable https for keycloak in a Jhipster-generated project. In Jhipster doc (https://www.jhipster.tech/security/), it says "In production, it is required by Keycloak that you use HTTPS. There are several ways to achieve this, including using a reverse proxy or load balancer that will manage HTTPS. We recommend that you read the Keycloak HTTPS documentation to learn more about this topic." And in the Keycloak doc, there are step that is "First, you must edit the standalone.xml, standalone-ha.xml, or host.xml file".

Sounds reasonable, right? But, if installing and running Keycloak server on mac, the configuration file is in /opt/jboss/keycloark..., but when running this keycloak within the jhipster-generated project (using the nice and easy command 'docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up'), I find that there is no such folder /opt/jboss/... Either I did something wrong, or it was in some other space like Docker container, or Jhipter container, or somewhere else. So the question is, how should we enable https on this Keycloak shipped with the Jhipster generated project?

Would appreciate it very much for any help from the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Expose https port `8443` of your Keycloak container and you will have selfsigned https, e.g.:

```
      ports:
        - 443:8443
```

+ use volumes if you have own TLS certificate, e.g.:

```
      volumes:
        - /path/my-cert.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
        - /path/my-cert.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I add this into the keycloak.yml, and can load https://localhost now (I test it first on localhost). But after I log in using my username and password, I got an error page, saying:

[invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 401 Unauthorized
http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster

As this project is generated by Jhipster, and keycloak is enclosed in it. I find it hard to figure where this error is. It seems some redirect that was original put there needs to be changed. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And because I am running nginx as a reverse-proxy, referring to https://www.mai1015.com/development/2019/05/05/docker-keycloak-proxy-behind-nginx/, so when I add 443:8443 in the ports of keycloak.yml, the KeyCloak does not start, because nginx also listens to 443.

Comment: let me make my question simpler (sorry the previous comments are kinda complicated). I have this Jhipster-generated project which uses Keycloak, and I change in the Keycloak admin panel saying every request needs https. Now if I  log in, it will report an error "https required". What exactly should I do, in keycloak yml, in application.yml, or in whatever other files, which can make this keycloak thing work with https? Have been stuck in this for a while. And in my opinion, next time I will build things from scratch up, never will use generation tool...maybe I am just stupid). Thanks a lot...

Comment: Sorry, but it is our of the scope of original question. Please accept answer, of it os correct and create new question with minimal reproducible example of your setup there. How community should know what and where did you configure.

Comment: Sure, thanks Jan. I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276409/enable-https-in-jhipster-project-which-uses-keycloak

By the way, how do I accept your answer? I have up-ed the vote, but not sure what else to do. Sorry, being new here.